# Translate HTML module from Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.7

I need to insert a language string inside a Custom HTML module on Joomla (1.7).

Like: `K2_READ_MORE` (and not `Read more`)

How?

Comment: Could you give some more information? Or show us what you have written in the custom module. It might help us to help you. On a different note, this would be a good question for http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers

Comment: Thanks, I have never read about Area 51 =D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in this way:

1. Create folder

> /templates/**YOUR-TEMPLATE**/html/mod_custom

1. Copy there the following file and edit it:

> /modules/mod_custom/tmpl/default.php

1. At approximately 14th line replace:

   <?php echo $module->content; ?>

with:

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('convertJText')) {
    function convertJText($str) { return JText::_($str); };
}
echo preg_replace("/\^\^\^([^\^]+)\^\^\^/ie",'convertJText("$1")', $module->content);
?>
```

Then you will be able to use translatable strings in your Custom HTML modules by using **^^^K2_READ_MORE^^^**

Answer (score 2):

Try the Sourcerer plugin:

http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer

Comment: Inside a Module I can't add PHP.

Comment: I modified my answer, I apologize I didn't see the 'Custom' word.